# html5 video custom controls

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a custom player design and was following HTML5 custom controls tutorials and hit a problem.

On executing `unmute` it shows `[objectHTML button Element]`, so what do i do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="320" autoplay>
<source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4"></source>
</video><br>
<button id="plbn" onclick="playPause()">Pause</button>
<button id="mute" onclick="mutevol()">Mute</button>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
function playPause() {
var plbtn = document.getElementById("plbn");
    if (vid.paused)     
        {vid.play();plbtn.innerHTML = "Pause";}
    else
        {vid.pause();plbtn.innerHTML = "Play";}
    }
function mutevol() {
var mutebtn = document.getElementById("mute");
    if(vid.muted == true)
        {vid.muted = false; 
        mutebtn.innerHTML = mute;}
    else
        {vid.muted = true; 
        mutebtn.innerHTML = unmute;} /*On execution it shows "[objectHTML button ELement]", so what do i do? */
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mute and unmute need quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mute and unmute should be strings, so use following:

```
mutebtn.innerHTML = "unmute";
mutebtn.innerHTML = "mute";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for correcting me. i never noticied that silly mistake